# Why is it called *adjunction* formula?

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, adjoint-operators

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, $Y$ a sub-manifold, and $i \colon Y \to X$ the corresponding embedding. Then one can prove that the corresponding canonical bundles satisfy
$$
\omega_X \big|_Y = \omega_Y \otimes \det(N_{Y/X})^* \label{eq:adjunction} \tag{1}
$$
where $\omega_X \big|_Y = i^*\omega_X$ and $N_{Y/X} = TX \big|_Y \big/ TY$ is the normal bundle.

**Why is this called the [adjunction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_formula)?** I suppose that this is a special case of some [adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors), but I can't figure out the corresponding functors.

---

I thought that maybe this relates to the identity for the $\mathcal{Hom}$ bundle
$$
\mathcal{Hom}(E,F) = E^* \otimes F
$$
which applied to \ref{eq:adjunction} gives
$$
\mathcal{Hom}(\det(N_{Y/X}),\omega_Y) = \omega_X \big|_Y = \det(T^*X) \big|_Y = \mathcal{Hom}(\det(TX) \big|_Y, X \times \Bbb{C})
$$
but I still can't make out the functors.

Comment: $\mathcal{Hom}(E,-)$  is left adjoint to  $-\otimes E$ for any bundle $E$. Maybe then you can figure it out.